# Unity and an IoC for Settings

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

After a somewhat lengthily discussion in the chat room, I have set up an IoC container with Unity to store my settings in.

This is my static IoC class:

```
public static class IoCContainer
{
    public static IUnityContainer Container = new UnityContainer();
}
```

In App.xaml.cs:

```
IoCContainer.Container.RegisterType<ApplicationSettingProvider<Theme>, ApplicationThemeProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
IoCContainer.Container.RegisterType<ApplicationSettingProvider<FontSize>, ApplicationFontSizeProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
IoCContainer.Container.RegisterType<ApplicationSettingProvider<AppVersion>, ApplicationStartupVersionProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Wherever I want to access my settings:

```
private ApplicationSettingProvider<Theme> _ThemeProvider = IoCContainer.Container.Resolve<ApplicationSettingProvider<Theme>>();
private ApplicationSettingProvider<FontSize> _FontSizeProvider = IoCContainer.Container.Resolve<ApplicationSettingProvider<FontSize>>();
private ApplicationSettingProvider<AppVersion> _StartupVersionProvider = IoCContainer.Container.Resolve<ApplicationSettingProvider<AppVersion>>();
```

And, an example setting, just to make everything complete:

```
public class ApplicationThemeProvider : ApplicationSettingProvider<Theme>
{
    public ApplicationThemeProvider()
    {
        ApplicationData.Current.DataChanged += (a, o) =>
        {
            CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                OnSettingChanged((Theme)ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["Theme"]);
            });
        };
    }

    public override Theme GetCurrentSetting()
    {
        object value;
        if (ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values.TryGetValue("Theme", out value))
        {
            int themeValue = (int)value;
            return (themeValue >= 0 && themeValue <= 2) ? (Theme)themeValue : Theme.Default;
        }
        return Theme.Default;
    }

    public override void SetCurrentSetting(Theme theme)
    {
        ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["Theme"] = (int)theme;
        ApplicationData.Current.SignalDataChanged();
    }
}
```

Which is based on:

```
public class SettingChangedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T NewSetting { get; private set; }

    public SettingChangedEventArgs(T newSetting)
    {
        NewSetting = newSetting;
    }
}

public abstract class ApplicationSettingProvider<T>
{
    public abstract T GetCurrentSetting();
    public abstract void SetCurrentSetting(T setting);

    public event EventHandler<SettingChangedEventArgs<T>> SettingChanged;
    public void OnSettingChanged(T newSetting)
    {
        var handler = SettingChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new SettingChangedEventArgs<T>(newSetting));
        }
    }
}
```

This review is primarily to make sure I am using Unity right.  Please tell me everything that can be improved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> public static class IoCContainer
> {
>     public static IUnityContainer Container = new UnityContainer();
> }
> ```

I've never used Unity, but this looks quite dangerous to me: your IoC container is accessible from anywhere in the code. Dependency Injection does not play well with anything `public static` - the IoC container is no exception here. In fact, the IoC container instance belongs in one, single place: your *composition root* - and that's app.xaml.xs. So instead of this:

> ```
> IoCContainer.Container.RegisterType<ApplicationSettingProvider<Theme>, ApplicationThemeProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
> IoCContainer.Container.RegisterType<ApplicationSettingProvider<FontSize>, ApplicationFontSizeProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
> IoCContainer.Container.RegisterType<ApplicationSettingProvider<AppVersion>, ApplicationStartupVersionProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
> ```

You should have that:

```
_container.RegisterType<ApplicationSettingProvider<Theme>, ApplicationThemeProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
_container.RegisterType<ApplicationSettingProvider<FontSize>, ApplicationFontSizeProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
_container.RegisterType<ApplicationSettingProvider<AppVersion>, ApplicationStartupVersionProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Where `_container` is an instance field of your `App` class. In a [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) application this setup code would be in the `OnStartup` override: the `UnityContainer` instance only ever lives at the *composition root* level.

Speaking of *composition*, you've either not included it, or all you're doing is the *registration* part. And this explains it:

> Wherever I want to access my settings:
>
> ```
> private ApplicationSettingProvider<Theme> _ThemeProvider = IoCContainer.Container.Resolve<ApplicationSettingProvider<Theme>>();
> private ApplicationSettingProvider<FontSize> _FontSizeProvider = IoCContainer.Container.Resolve<ApplicationSettingProvider<FontSize>>();
> private ApplicationSettingProvider<AppVersion> _StartupVersionProvider = IoCContainer.Container.Resolve<ApplicationSettingProvider<AppVersion>>();
> ```

That's exactly the **opposite** of [dependency-injection](/questions/tagged/dependency-injection): everywhere you're accessing your settings, you have a *tight coupling* with that `static class IoCContainer` and its `public static IUnityContainer` field.

That's the *Service Locator* anti-pattern: anyone, anywhere, has access to anything that's registered with the IoC container. The typical *Service Locator* passes the container around as a dependency - but your is worse, because being a `public static` utility class, it becomes an *ambient context* that's accessible at any given time by anyone that wants to use it.

IoC containers are much, much more powerful than that. IoC stands for *Inversion of Control* - that means your types don't *ask* the container to resolve an instance of a service, but rather they *tell* it what their dependencies are, and the IoC container injects them... usually through the constructor.

---

## The Hollywood Principle: *Don't Call Them, They'll Call You*

I'm going to have to make some things up here, because you've supplied us with the *dependencies*, but not with anything that depends on them.

So let's say your application is controller by a `MainWindowViewModel`.

This `MainWindowViewModel` class needs to access the settings; its constructor will *statically document this fact*, by taking in an *interface* that represents some `SettingsProvider` - here you've done that with an abstract class:

```
private readonly ApplicationSettingProvider<Theme> _themeSettings;
private readonly ApplicationSettingProvider<FontSize> _fontSizeSettings;
private readonly ApplicationSettingProvider<AppVersion> _appVersionSettings;

private readonly IView _view;

public MainWindowViewModel(ApplicationSettingProvider<Theme> themeSettings,
                           ApplicationSettingProvider<FontSize> fontSizeSettings,
                           ApplicationSettingProvider<AppVersion> appVersionSettings,
                           IView view)
{
    _themeSettings = themeSettings;
    _fontSizeSettings = fontSizeSettings;
    _appVersionSettings = appVersionSettings;

    _view = view;
}
```

The class may have more dependencies - the key is that it receives them all into its constructor.

> **Constructor Bloating**
>
> Everyone has their threshold. For most people, 3-4 constructor parameters is the upper limit, 5 in the extreme cases. When you start seeing that your constructor has too many dependencies, it's a sign that your class is responsible for too many things - you should then extract a class, wrap it with an interface, and inject that interface instead. In this case there could be a single `IAppSettings` abstraction injected there, and the implementation for that interface would receive the 3 `SettingsProvider<T>` into its own constructor.
>
> But let's say these are the only 3 dependencies you have to deal with for now... plus the `IView`.

When you register the types with your IoC container, you're telling it what types to use to resolve the dependencies when you *compose* the application - that's the step you missed.

#### Back to the *Composition Root*

```
_container.RegisterType<ApplicationSettingProvider<Theme>, ApplicationThemeProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
_container.RegisterType<ApplicationSettingProvider<FontSize>, ApplicationFontSizeProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
_container.RegisterType<ApplicationSettingProvider<AppVersion>, ApplicationStartupVersionProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

// again, I don't know how Unity works - this is just for the concept:
_container.RegisterType<MainWindowViewModel,MainWindowViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
_container.RegisterType<IView,MainWindow>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Now the IoC container knows about `MainWindowViewModel`, and all of its dependencies. The last thing to do is to *resolve* them, and get your app started:

```
var viewModel = _container.Resolve<MainWindowViewModel>();
viewModel.Show();
```

What just happened here? The container used the configurations you gave it, and constructor-injected all the dependencies of the `viewModel` - that's why that method is called `Resolve`: it *resolves* the entire application's *depedency graph* with a single call.

**The only place you're allowed to do this is in the composition root!**

That's why I said in chat, that you cannot do Dependency Injection *halfway*: you need to go DI *all the way*, and register *all dependencies of every single type*; every type needs to have its dependencies constructor-injected, otherwise you're breaking the pattern and you're going to have to `new` things up manually and thus introduce *tight coupling*.